# Numpy slow on server pc

Tags: numpy, performance, server

I installed numpy on a server computer but Numpy functions are working extremely slow compared to my home PC. I have tried different numpy versions. I am not sure how to start debugging the issue. Any help is appreciated. An example code and run time.

```
import numpy as np    
import time
              
print('numpy version', np.__version__)    
                                          
def NormFilter(img):    
    MIN_BOUND = -1000.0    
    MAX_BOUND = 400.0      
    img = (img - MIN_BOUND) / (MAX_BOUND - MIN_BOUND)    
    return img                                           
                  
    
patch_np = np.random.rand(140,512,512)*2048.0   
                      
start = time.time()    
_ = NormFilter(patch_np)    
print('np time', time.time() - start)
```

output:

```
numpy version 1.21.3
np time 14.651761531829834
```

Here's numpy.show_config()

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2,AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX
    not found = AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

The CPU is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6230 CPU @ 2.10GHz.

Edit

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Python 3.8.0

Comment: What OS are you using and which Python version?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS 
Python 3.8.0

Comment: I have about the same class processor but with *less* cores and my timings are like 30-50 times faster. My guess no1 is that the server is already overloaded with computation and maybe his RAM is working with swap what would choke your code as well.

Comment: Second guess is something went wrong with `openblas`, [try to use MKL instead](https://medium.com/@black_swan/using-mkl-to-boost-numpy-performance-on-ubuntu-f62781e63c38)

Comment: To check if the problem comes from the RAM usage, you can analyse the time take to compute a 2, 4, 6 and 8 times smaller array and see if the time is quite proportional to the size. For the overload, you can use the `perf stat` Linux tool to understand the root of the problem (and report it in your question if you do not understand the result).

Comment: Thanks.  The problem seemed to have solved itself on its own. Most probably there was a background process creating the issue.